# Dropdown on hover in Bootstrap 4.1

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, bootstrap-4

I have a website in which I have created dropdown using [Bootstrap 4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css). At this moment, the dropdown is working on click.

The HTML code which I have used in order to create the dropdown are:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      main menu
    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">D</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/M';" class="btn btn-default">R</button>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that I can see the dropdown items **(A,B,C,D)** on hover.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```css
.navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      main menu
    </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">D</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/M';" class="btn btn-default">R</button>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a similar question. Suppose on hover of `item D`, is there any way I can create another dropdown ? Like, if we hover on D; items E, F, G, H,....are created to whatever I want.

Comment: Yes you can. However you need to maintain the nesting of elements.

Answer (score 0):

If You Want to show dropdown on hover in bootstrap then you need to visit here here is very easy way to do that . there are less number of code of css and your issue will fix

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owdqNLzII38

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32601594)