# Dropdown submenu on hover in Bootstrap 4.1

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, bootstrap-4

I am working on a website in which I want to create a **dropdown submenu** on hover in [Bootstrap 4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)

The HTML code which I have used in order to create a dropdown menu on hover are:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      main menu
    </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">P</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Q</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">R</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">S</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/M';" class="btn btn-default">R</button>

  </ul>
</div>
```

The above HTML code is the working code which displays **P, Q, R, and S on hover**.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above now so that on **hover of S; dropdown items T, U, V, and W are shown**.

Answer (score 4):

You could just apply the inception concept and put back another `dropdown-toggle` element inside the menu.

To open the sub-menu on hover you have to wrap the content inside a container to apply the `:hover` css styling `display:block` on the `.dropdown-menu` child element that contains the submenu links.

```css
/* makes main-menu open on hover */
.menu-item:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

/* makes sub-menu S open on hover */
.submenu-item:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <li class="menu-item nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        main menu
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">P</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Q</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">R</a>
        <div class="submenu-item">
          <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle dropright" href="#" id="navbarDropdownSubMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            S
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownSubMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">T</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">U</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">V</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">W</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/M';" class="btn btn-default">R</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have replicated your code in my code but its working on click. I am wondering if there is any way we can do that on hover.

Comment: According to Bootstrap dropdown documentation it is a desired behavior to be on click instead of on hover: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#overview

Comment: If you see my code above in the question, the dropdown items (P, Q, R and S) get displayed on hover. So I was wondering if there is any way we can do for submenu.

Comment: I used your snippet and its not opening on hover ... am I missing something?

Comment: This is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/v1qz503u/) I have used and its working on hover.

Comment: I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413782/dropdown-on-hover-in-bootstrap-4-1/51413876?noredirect=1#comment89799405_51413876) on July 19th on SO. I have copied the accepted answer in my code.

Comment: ok now i see ... this wasn't in this question tho, let me take a look if i can find something

Comment: Sounds good. To repeat, I have copied the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413782/dropdown-on-hover-in-bootstrap-4-1/51413876?noredirect=1#comment89799405_51413876) and its working fine on hover. Now, I want to make submenu on hover.

Comment: I had to tweek it a little by wrapping the sub-menu inside a container to apply the `display: block` css on hover

Comment: Did you edit the code above ? I can't see any changes.

Comment: I did although its subtle! try refreshing :P

Comment: I have placed your code in my code and the submenu item is working only on click.

Comment: You probably missed something (the css that sets `display: block`?) ... cause its working when you run the code

Comment: I am checking. Stay tuned.

Comment: you copied the CSS + the HTML code ? Look at the running example ... its working on rollover, this means it might has something to do on how to copy-paste the whole thing to your application

Comment: Ok, it worked now. I am wondering what changes I should do now so that I can shift the dropdown towards the right ? At this moment, it is going all the way towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you've already figured out that isn't possible with the default bootstrap 4.1 classes.

You can achieve the desired effect using some jQuery and CSS.

First, create a div with a custom class and a list with the items you need, TUVW in your case.

After in CSS, you can hide your list container and handle its position.

In jQuery you can track mouse hover event('mouseenter mouseleave') puting your logic to show/hide the list container.

Comment: I am wondering if you can give me pointer how we can do in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Sorry but I think you cant do this in pure bootstrap. You'll need some tweak to get it working.

Comment: If you want to try some tweak it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183824/7844113